# How can i replace a fragment inside another fragment using Nav Controller?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, navigation, uinavigationcontroller

Let say I've a Fragment container view in Main Fragment and I want to place two fragments by the Click of Buttons present in main Fragment. On one button click, the First fragment is Placed inside that container and on other button that fragment is replaced by the 2nd fragment. So How can we do it using navigation Component.

I done this through the following code:

```
``val controller by lazy { Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.fragmentContainer)}

btnOne.setOnClickListener{
controller.navigate(R.id.oneFragment)
}

btnOne.setOnClickListener{
controller.navigate(R.id.otherFragment)
}``
```

I've Tried this Code but it gives me an Error of :ID does not reference a View inside this Activity

Comment: As per your error, it seems like an issue with the ID that you have defined in the navigation graph. Cross-check with your IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the FragmentContainer inside the Main Activity of your app, then in the Nav_graph you can set the Main Fragment as Home destination. From the Nav_graph you will be able to set all possible destination between various fragment.
Refer to the documentation :

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started